# Adding MP3s to iTunes 10 doesn't work for some files

Tags: music, audio, itunes, mp3

I have recently upgraded to iTunes 10. I had some MP3 files which I would like to add to the library. In the past I have dragged the folder into the iTunes "Library" section which has added all the songs, but this time it only added the last two songs of a ~20 song album. Adding the files individually does not work either, and "File > Add to Library" does the same thing (only adds two of the songs).

Is this a known issue, and is there a workaround?

Comment: The same happens with iTunes 11, and Quick Look is able to play these files with no problems

Comment: Facing the same issue, tried few but not getting through.. any definitive solution is appreciated... In my case, the mp3 content was earlier purchased through windows phone.. i hope thats not the issue, since some files are accepted by itunes, whereas some are not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the issue was related to improperly encoded files. I'm not sure if it was the container layout that was malformed or if the audio was incorrectly encoded, or even if it was just in a format that iTunes could not understand, but re-encoding the files as MP3 allowed them to be read by iTunes.

Comment: What did you use to re-encode the files? The files I have are already MP3.

Comment: Sorry I cant remember. I frequently use Handbrake for video, maybe it can do audio too?

Answer (score 2):

In many cases, improper tagging causes the files to go weird places. I suggest you create a smart playlist that shows you “new added” stuff:
[image: New Today]

I usually have the same problem with mp3 with dubious tagging.

Comment: Using this method is exactly what I did to determine that they had no been added, but this is certainly a good answer, thank you :)

Comment: Have you double-checked file permissions both in the iTunes music folder and in the mp3’s that you’re adding? It’s a weird issue for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading for me made iTunes forget where the music library was (I use an external HD)... putting back the directory fixed it for me.... goto advanced settings, iTunes Media folder location, change... select media folder "iTunes Library". If you don't know where your songs are exactly then right-click on a song and "show in finder", that will give you an idea.

I was able to add mp3's etc to itunes after that... :)